# Some symbols showing in Excel VBA code editor

Tags: excel, vba

When I open the VBA code editor some symbols are showing at every line. Please suggest to fix the issue.

Attached the screenshot for your reference:

[image: Symbols in vba code editor]

Comment: What is the name of the font set in VBE > Tools > Editor Format > Font?

Comment: What is the source of that file? Who created it, was it you? Did you copy that code from a website? Did you import the code from a `.bas` file? Do they also appear at the end of the lines if you write code on your own using the keyboard? Please clarify.

Comment: It's my own program.. it is like a shadow images once reopen the file symbols get vary.. and there is no issues with the font style too.

Comment: Does it happen in new files too? Please test that. If it happens in new files it is a general issue with your computer. Then try to re-install Office. If new files are OK and the issue is only in this one file then probably your file is corrupted.